# Adding Alloy UI External Script in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui, alloy-ui

I am creating a aui script in jsp page and it worked successfully but when I **create a externally copy of that script and including it using liferay-portlet.xml** it is not working

After adding External Script no events get Fired.

Can anyone help me on how to include external aui-script file ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you fire that function or call it in your jsp? With the call in liferay-portlet.xml you are just including this javascript file. Could you see if it's been loaded on the browser inspector?

Comment: http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/02/introduction-to-aui-java-script-in.html

Comment: @Jorge : i have seen the dev. console. file is getting loaded.

Comment: @ParkashKumar : i have read the link you have given above. but it doesn't show how to add external aui script in liferay

Comment: Could you edit your question and add more info about the script?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this problem occur due to the `<portlet:namespace/>` tag. In the external script you have to explicitly set the value of your portlet namespace.